# Delete breakpoint set using edebug-defun

Tags: debugging, edebug

I set break-point in function

`(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (function
       (lambda nil 
         (if (or (string-match "llvm" buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "nvvm" buffer-file-name))
         (progn
           (c-set-style "llvm.org"))))))`

I am unable to remove the break-point. This code fragment is in `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: Reevaluate the form to remove the `edebug`-instrumentation. When debugging press `u` to delete a breakpoint previously set with `b`.

Comment: Sorry pressing `u` gives message: `No breakpoint here`.
_Reevaluate the form to remove the edebug-instrumentation_
I am pressing C-x C-e to reevaluate. That didn't help either.

Comment: Sorry, I did misunderstand your actual question because you chose the wrong wording. You do not really set breakpoints with `edebug-defun` but you instrument a function or a form for debugging in this way. Setting breakpoints works with pressing `b` when you are in an `edebug` session. And breakpoints set with `b` can be deleted with `u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to add a lambda to a hook if you want to debug this lambda. `edebug` adds its own stuff so that you cannot easily remove or redefine the function. If you try you end up with two functions in the hook.

Rather define a function such as `my-c-mode-common-hook-function` and instrument that one.

```el
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook-function ()
  "some useful documentation"
  (if (or (string-match "llvm" buffer-file-name)
             (string-match "nvvm" buffer-file-name))
         (progn
           (c-set-style "llvm.org"))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'my-c-mode-common-hook-function)
```

You can then easily instrument `my-c-mode-common-hook-function` for debugging.

Comment: So essentially don't instrument a lambda hook with `edebug-defun`?
Thanks.